# Java CSV read file validation doesnt work

Tags: java, bluej

Background : The code is supposed to go through a csv file (second link), find the username and password and either confirm and display all the info or write error. But now it only says error. Cheers in advance.

http://pastebin.com/YBpKRKe2
http://pastebin.com/9K3nwYG3

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CSVRead
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {

        BufferedReader CSVFile =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test123.csv"));
        int invalidvar = 1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your email");
        String email =input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your password");
        String password =input.nextLine();

        String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read first line.
        // The while checks to see if the data is null. If
        // it is, we've hit the end of the file. If not,
        // process the data.

        while (dataRow != null)
        {
            String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\\t");


            if ((dataArray[0].equals(email))
            &&(dataArray[1].equals(password)))
            {
                System.out.println("You email is " +dataArray[0]+".");
                System.out.println("You password is " +dataArray[1]+".");
                System.out.println("You first name is " +dataArray[2]+".");
                System.out.println("You second name is " +dataArray[3]+".");
                System.out.println("You street name is " +dataArray[4]+".");
                System.out.println("You city name is " +dataArray[5]+".");
                System.out.println("You postcode is " +dataArray[6]+".");
            }

            else
            {
            System.out.println("Error");
            break;
            }


            dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        }
        // Close the file once all data has been read.
        CSVFile.close();

        // End the printout with a blank line.
        System.out.println();

    } //main()
} // CSVRead
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking the first record after the CSV header. You need to continue checking the records until the `EOF` is reached:

```
boolean found = false;
while (!found && dataRow != null) {
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\\t");

    if ((dataArray[0].equals(email)) && (dataArray[1].equals(password))) {
        System.out.println("You email is " + dataArray[0] + ".");
            ...
        found = true;
    } 

    dataRow = csvFile.readLine();
}

System.out.println("Result of CSV search: " + found);
```

---

*Some side notes:*

- IO Streams should be closed in a `finally` block.
- [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) indicate variables should start with a lowercase letter.